# how to write a comparison loop in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table named "memberdata". In this table, the columns are "id(pk), F_name,L_name,Tel,gender(F/M) and birth_date(varchar). Now, I need to make a comparison, for each duplicate phone number in the memberdata table, if some records have a gender of M and others have a gender of F keep only the oldest female and remove all others to the scrubs table. Else if all have the same gender remove the records containing all but the record containing the oldest birth_date to the scrubs table. 
I'm confused how code a comparison loop in Mysql.
Please help me
Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No loop.  SQL is a "set" language.  So do all the moves in a single statement.  (Actually it a fixed number of statements, not depending on the number of rows.)

Change that date from VARCHAR to DATE !!

Add this "compound" index `INDEX(Tel, birth_date)`

Oooo; this is a complex problem.

Let me ignore the M/F aspect of the problem for the moment -- this is complex enough even without it.

The "keep" query.  (We won't use it, but it is a simple starting point.)  See if this is the ones you need to "keep":

```
SELECT  m1.*
    FROM  memberdata AS m1
    JOIN
      ( SELECT Tel, MAX(birth_date) AS birth_date
            FROM  memberdata 
            GROUP BY  Tel
      ) AS m2 USING (Tel, birth_date);
```

If that is OK, then this (I'll call it the "Scrub" query) should fetch the rows that need to be scrubbed; does it?:

```
SELECT  m1.*
    FROM  memberdata AS m1
    LEFT JOIN
      ( SELECT Tel, MAX(birth_date) AS birth_date
            FROM  memberdata 
            GROUP BY  Tel
      ) AS m2 USING (Tel, birth_date)
     WHERE m2.id IS NULL;
```

To *copy* the rows into Scrubs:

```
INSERT INTO Scrubs
    SELECT... -- the second SELECT above ;
```

To remove the copied rows from memberdata,

```
DELETE FROM memberdata
    USING Scrubs, memberdata
    WHERE Scrubs.id = memberdata.id;
```

Now, to think about the messy M/F requirement.  Let me rephrase:

- If all F (or all M), Scrub all but the oldest;
- If mixture of M and F, Scrub all but oldest F (and keep all M?).

See if this gets all-F phones:

```
SELECT  Tel, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT gender ORDER BY  gender SEPARATOR '') AS FM
        FROM  memberdata
        GROUP BY  Tel
        HAVING  FM = 'F';
```

Well, we somehow need to JOIN variants this query to the other(s) to the 'scrub' query to limit it to just F, etc. and run each version.  After those are working, the DELETE will do all the DELETEs in a single query.  So, I guessing it will be 4 statements (3 INSERT..SELECTs, then 1 DELETE), total.

Munch on these comments; come back if you need more help.

OK I have not figured out how to do the FM case.  Would you like your money back for this consultation?  I could send you a check for $0.00.

Comment: Thank you very very much Rick, it's very detailed. I was thinking using "do,while" in a stored procedure. I'm definitely going to spend times on your answer. I'll come back with my money! lol